# AVAssetWriter - an unknown error code=-16351

Tags: ios, swift, h.264, avassetwriter, avassetwriterinput

I`m using [AVAssetWriter](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetwriter) to write raw video data (H264/Mpeg4) stream into a file without re-encoding. After first two chunks of data successfully written I get an error:

```
let isAppended = videoInput!.append(sampleBuffer!)  


Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 \"The operation could not be completed\"   
UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16351),   
NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x1c085dee0   
{Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16351 \"(null)\"}}
```

Can`t find any documentation on what does that error mean and how I can fix it?

Comment: You can search error codes at [www.osstatus.com](https://www.osstatus.com), but unfortunately this page doesn't found the `-16351` code.

Comment: what was the solution finally?